# The toolbar can't show up

Tags: android, toolbar, appcompatactivity

```
public abstract class SingleFragmentActivity extends AppCompatActivity

public class CrimeListActivity extends SingleFragmentActivity
```

The following the layout xml file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <LinearLayout
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent">
         <include layout="@layout/content_criminal"/>
     </LinearLayout>
```

The following is the manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.littlebear.android.criminalintent"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".CrimeListActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".CrimePagerActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The following is the content_criminal.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">



</FrameLayout>
```

Toolbar didn't show up in my CrimeListActivity.

But in CrimePagerActivity, which class extends AppCompatActivity, show the toolBar. I can't find the reason. Please help me. Any advice will be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Show me your AndroidManifest.xml, and what theme are you using? And show us content_criminal too

Comment: I have already updated it. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"> this tag from manifest . You set manually no actionbar theme in manifest . So delete this code your code run perfectly

Answer (score 0):

It's a rookie mistake. Forgive me. I am really rookie for Android.

```
 <activity
                android:name=".CrimeListActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

If i delete the line of 'android:theme=@style/AppTheme.NoActionbar',the toolbar just show up. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

if you use `AppCompatActivity` does not mean you have a toolbar. 
I guess your `AppTheme.NoActionBar` extends  `<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

Then parent `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` **had set**

**`<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>`

`<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>`**

Then can see `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

You just modify this `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar` to `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

```
<activity
                android:name=".CrimeListActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
</activity>
```